# Strange Onion and i don't know what it's

Tags: vegetable

Today i cutting my onion and i saw so many verbs like this in it.  I searched about it through google lens and manually also but unable to find the reason of this. I doubt is it serious case ? [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is the unripe flowering parts of an onion that's [bolted](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/vegetables/vgen/what-is-bolting-what-it-means-when-a-plant-bolts.htm), this can occur if the weather's been hot:

[image: an unopened flower.]

<sup>Copyright through: [Greensideup.ie](https://greensideup.ie/bolting-vegetables/onion-flower/) 2021, fair usage.</sup>

This would be more what it's like when the flowers open:

[image: an opened flower]

<sup>Copyright through: [asergeev.com](https://www.asergeev.com/pictures/archives/compress/2014/1427/03.htm) 2021, fair usage.</sup>

As you see, they come in a variety of colours, the ones in my garden are purple and red. They're edible and tasty in salads.

Comment: Ok so my one is also safe and it's normal.  Right ?

Comment: Assuming that what you had in the first place was an onion, then yes. But to be sure, check out [hyacinths](https://freethoughtblogs.com/affinity/2020/03/16/wild-hyacinths/), they can look similar. Be assured that only the onion family (inc. garlic, chives, ornamental onions) smell like themselves. If it whiffs like an onion, then it's safe to eat. If it's an ornamental onion, it's safe, but not as tasty. @AmitMittal

Comment: Ohkey , thank you so much for all the details